# При выполнении команды import cv2 ошибка KeyError: cv2

Tags: python-3.5

Программа:

```
# python test_imagenet.py --image images/dog_beagle.png

# import the necessary packages
from keras.preprocessing import image as image_utils
from imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
from imagenet_utils import preprocess_input
from vgg16 import VGG16
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to the input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load the original image via OpenCV so we can draw on it and display
# it to our screen later
orig = cv2.imread(args["image"])

# load the input image using the Keras helper utility while ensuring
# that the image is resized to 224x224 pxiels, the required input
# dimensions for the network -- then convert the PIL image to a
# NumPy array
print("[INFO] loading and preprocessing image...")
image = image_utils.load_img(args["image"], target_size=(224, 224))
image = image_utils.img_to_array(image)

# our image is now represented by a NumPy array of shape (3, 224, 224),
# but we need to expand the dimensions to be (1, 3, 224, 224) so we can
# pass it through the network -- we'll also preprocess the image by
# subtracting the mean RGB pixel intensity from the ImageNet dataset
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
image = preprocess_input(image)

# load the VGG16 network
print("[INFO] loading network...")
model = VGG16(weights="imagenet")

# classify the image
print("[INFO] classifying image...")
preds = model.predict(image)
(inID, label) = decode_predictions(preds)[0]

# display the predictions to our screen
print("ImageNet ID: {}, Label: {}".format(inID, label))
cv2.putText(orig, "Label: {}".format(label), (10, 30),
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imshow("Classification", orig)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

При выполнении `import cv2` ошибка `KeyError: 'cv2'`.

Windows 7 32 bit Python 3.5 Visual Studio 2010 opencv 2.4.10

Comment: opencv установлен?

Comment: @vp_arth opencv установлен версия 2.4.10

Comment: Приведите полный трейс ошибки

Comment: если вы можете продемонстрировать ошибку одной строчкой: `import cv2`, то уберите любой другой код из вопроса. [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Как сделать, чтоб эта команда:

```
cv2.putText(orig, "Label: {}".format(label), (10, 30),
cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

текст на русском писала?